# Can I fix my unset Crème Brûlée bars

Tags: creme-brulee

I followed this recipe:
[image]

and messed up the temp to bake at because I confused myself when I was doing it. I wanted to make this for my class and so I doubled the recipe as well. I have to bring it in tomorrow morning and was wondering if there’s anything I can do to fix the custard.

It is completely soupy, I would say it maybe thickened a little bit like if you added heavy cream to coffee since I let it sit for the past 3 hours. I have made this recipe before successfully in my cooking class but I actually wasn’t there for when it was taken out of the oven and the setting process after so I wasn’t completely sure what it was supposed to look like.

Comment: What temperature _were_ they baked at? Was it sitting in the fridge or on the counter?

Comment: I accidentally baked them 25 degrees too low, so instead of 300, 275 and after i got them out they set for an hour on the counter and then 2 more hours in the fridge

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late for "tomorrow morning" but I would've baked them again at 190°F to evaporate most of the extra moisture.

**Why 190°F?** Well, that is below the boiling point of water but will still get rid of the soupy texture by removing the excess of water without over-baking the entire thing.

**Alternatively**, you can also just rename the end product to "Crème Anglaise Brûlée" as that is what you ended up with: still tastes good, but just has a different texture and who knows that some people will like your version better as it's "lighter" then the original!!!

## :-)